# Blur UIImage not clipping (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, cifilter

I have the code below to blur an image from a UIImageView. It then places that image into the UIImageView.
Before the blur effect is applied the image clips and is set to `ScaleAspectFill` but once the effect is applied it stretches the image instead. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

```
let rectangle = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(xPosPix+100, yPosPix, widthPix, heightPix))

rectangle.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
rectangle.frame = CGRectMake(xPosPix+100, yPosPix, widthPix, heightPix)
rectangle.layer.opacity = opacity
rectangle.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
rectangle.clipsToBounds = true
self.view.addSubview(rectangle)

var image = rectangle.image
var imageToBlur = CIImage(image: image)
var blurfilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
blurfilter.setValue(imageToBlur, forKey: "inputImage")
var resultImage = blurfilter.valueForKey("outputImage") as! CIImage
var blurredImage = UIImage(CIImage: resultImage)
rectangle.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
rectangle.clipsToBounds = true
rectangle.image = blurredImage
```

Comment: May I ask why you don't just use the built-in `BlurEffectView`?

Comment: I am using Parse.com and I need to create the effect using the image from Parse.com

Comment: So? You could still use the built-in one. Just put the BlurView on a higher z.

Comment: I would also not like the BlueView to have a black/white colour to it. I would like it to appear like the image is blurred.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want

```
rectangle.layer.masksToBounds = true;
```

instead of the second

```
rectangle.clipsToBounds = true
```

Also if you are using layoutConstraints, they love to mess of corner radii. If that's the case try setting the corner radius property in layoutSubviews

Comment: It seems to be the `ScaleAspectFill` part that is causing a problem. It is stretching/squashing the image instead of fitting it to the shortest side as it usually does.

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems to me that you're looking for `.ScaleAspectFit` instead of `.ScaleAspectFill`?